# The optimum way of changing Material UI react theme at runtime

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React and Material UI and still am trying to grasp the composition over inheritance.
I am trying to achieve switching to dark/light theme at runtime in a react app. I have achieved it somehow but with lots of code duplication. I am sure there is a better way.
Here is what I have so far:

Theme.js

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    
export const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
 //.....a lot of items
});

export const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "light",
  },

 //.....duplicating same items as above
});
```

App.js

```
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from "../shared/Theme";

const App = ({
  theme
}) => {

 return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
      {/*Components...*/}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

The theme props is getting injected using redux and its doing its job fine. This is workable solution but not the best one.
I found in Material UI documentation that we can have [outer and inner theme provider][1] and I tried doing the following (but it didn't work):

```
<ThemeProvider theme={…} >
  
  <ThemeProvider theme={outerTheme => ({ darkMode: true, ...outerTheme })}>
   {...Component}
  </ThemeProvider>
</ThemeProvider>
```

I am aware of useStyle hook but it just lets you create class names that you can use in your component. What I want is: take a certain section of the existing theme object and replace a property in it.
Any help will is appreciated. Thanks for reading this far!
[1]: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#main-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Duplication" is a problem when there is property-value repetition, otherwise is an alternate configuration, that is, repeating objects or their properties are not an issue. If there is no property-value repetition, using separate objects is the way, [MUI does it](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js), so you are right on track.

Now, Assuming you meant property-value repetition (shared styling) at:

```js
//.....duplicating same items as above
```

where there is property-value repetition mixed with alternate configuration within your objects, and based on your goal:

> take a certain section of the existing theme object and replace a property in it

Try a factory method:

```js
const createThemeOptions = (isDarkMode)=>({
   palette: {
    mode: isDarkMode? "dark" : "light", // alternate configuration
   },
   primary: {
      main: indigo['A700'], // property-value repetition(shared styling)
   },
   secondary: {
      main: isDarkMode? deepOrange['A200'] : deepOrange['900'], // alternate configuration
   },
  // make your other object properties shared or alternate...
});
export const darkTheme = createMuiTheme(createThemeOptions(true));
export const lightTheme = createMuiTheme(createThemeOptions());
```

Comment: I was of opinion that I am missing some cool hook or pattern that can help achieve what I was trying to do! Your answer looks cool and simple at same time. While the factory input just decides the palette.type property : :value, rest of property:value are shared. Will try this later during the day and mark as answer! Cheers David!